# Otimizando uma tabela Mysql com 40 campos

Tags: mysql

Olá, pessoal! Possuo uma tabela em Mysql com 40 campos, trata-se de um sistema de currículos. Estou fazendo a otimização tanto da tabela, como das próprias consultas executadas no PHP.

A questão é que para realizar buscas por perfis específicos, utiliza-se 20 desses campos, ou seja, fica uma consulta "pesada". Quando um determinado campo não é utilizado pelo usuário no momento de preencher os dados da busca, ela não é incluida em minha query. De toda forma, quando fui configurar os meus índices, vi que o máximo aceitável é 16 colunas. Por isso estou aqui para pedir uma opinião de vocês.

Confira abaixo alguns dos campos desta tabela:

```
cur_nome
cur_cpf
cur_senha
cur_nascimento
cur_estado_civil
cur_endereco
cur_estado
cur_cidade
cur_area1  (área de interesse 1) -> recebe um id de outra tabela
cur_area2  (área de interesse 2) -> recebe um id de outra tabela
cur_area3  (área de interesse 3) -> recebe um id de outra tabela
cur_habilitacao_a (carteira de habilitacao a) -> Recebe Sim ou Não
cur_habilitacao_b (carteira de habilitacao b) -> Recebe Sim ou Não
cur_habilitacao_c (carteira de habilitacao c) -> Recebe Sim ou Não
cur_habilitacao_d (carteira de habilitacao d) -> Recebe Sim ou Não
cur_habilitacao_e (carteira de habilitacao e) -> Recebe Sim ou Não
```

Com base na sugestão de um amigo nos comentários abaixo, peguei essa tabela e a dividi em três, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
Tabela1  com 15 campos
Tabela2  com 15 campos
Tabela3  com 10 campos
```

A Tabela2 e Tabela3 possuem como chave estrangeira (id da Tabela1) a própria chave primária.

Uma dúvida que tive é a seguinte:

Supondo que todos os campos são submetidos de uma só vez, no momento eu que gravar os dados, então eu faria 3 inserts no mysql, certo?

exemplo:

```
sql1 = insert into Tabela1 (campos) values (valores);
sql2 = insert into Tabela2 (campos) values (valores);
sql3 = insert into Tabela3 (campos) values (valores);
```

Nesse caso, para eu garantir que a Tabela2 e Tabela3 irão receber em suas chaves estrangeiras, a primária da Tabela1, é recomendável eu resgatar o valor do id gravado da tabela1, e assim fazer sua referência nas tabelas 2 e 3? Ficaria assim:

```
 sql1 = insert into Tabela1 (campos) values (valores);
 $idgravado = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);                         

 sql2 = insert into Tabela2 (tab2_codigo, outros_campos) values ($idgravado, valores);
 sql3 = insert into Tabela3 (tab3_codigo, outros_campos) values ($idgravado, valores);
```

O que me dizem pessoal?

Comment: Isso é só para pesquisa? Precisas ter os campos todos para pesquisa? A pergunta está um bocado ampla, porque depende de muitas coisas. O ideal era não ter tantos campos na pesquisa... Mas se você precisa, o que se poderá fazer?

Comment: Eu faria também, uma tabela por etapa, e depois usava o join pra buscar os registros pertinentes, fica muito melhor pra adicionar, consultar, inclusive, se você quiser consultar um registro em especifico, de uma etapa especifica, não precisa buscar em toda tabela, só busca o necessário mesmo.

Comment: Ola, André e Jorge, fiz uma edição em minha pergunta com algumas dúvidas sobre essa questão de divisão de tabelas em mais, veja acima.

Comment: Me parece justo, Jorge manja mais de SQL, mas eu faria o mesmo procedimento que lhe disse, e recupero o id da tabela principal e insiro nas outras pertinentes.

Comment: Irei uitlizar ao todo uns 16 campos para pesquisa, é necessário consultar os registros atraves de diversos critérios.

Comment: Vou fazer isso então, obrigado voces.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, o ideal seria você criar várias tabelas por exemplo:

1. tblDadosPessoais
2. tblEndereco
3. tblExperiencia

Assim depois você poderia usar o `INNER JOIN` para buscar dados em outras tabelas com o mesmo índice. Dê uma lida neste [artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/as-vantagens-do-uso-de-padronizacao-em-objetos-no-banco-de-dados/3221).

Comment: Olá Cleidimar, Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. Vou fazer uma modificação em minha pergunta para sanar algumas dúvidas em relação à sua sugestão.